# Difference between get and match in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the difference between `get` and `match` in rails used for routing?

For example, using `get`, I can write

```
get '/users' "users#index", as => 'all_users'
```

And can't I do the same thing using `match` like the following:

```
match '/users' => 'users#index', as => 'all_users'
```

When I should choose one and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` defines a route that allow request via the `HTTP GET` method. `get` is prefered if only want to respond to one method:

```
get 'users', to: 'users#index', as: 'all_users'
```

If you want to respond to multiple method you can use `match`, but should still define the allowed methods for security reasons:

```
match 'user', to: 'users#index', as: 'all_users', via: [:get, :post]
```

Quote from the [Rails Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match):

> You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.

Answer (score 4):

`get`, `post` and all other related methods are only helpers and they use `match` underneath. You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1d94fa0de3fdc8d2dbc60aacdd168a4f2dea146e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb). Use `match` when you need to set the route for multiple verbs (see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints)).